# Rotation for view when viewcontroller locked to portrait in ios6/ios7

Tags: ios

I got a view controller which is something like facebook's status feed vc which is looked to portrait.
when tapping an image the vc create a custom 'full image view' and add it to it's super view.
while the viewcontroller is locked to portrait I still want to let the user to be able rotate the device to see the image in landscape mode as well..
when closing the 'full image view' the custom view remove itself from the superview, in that moment I want to lock the vc view to portrait.

Bottom line, I want the vc to be locked to portrait but let the user the option to see the full image in both orientation.

Comment: I've made my answer more precise now. Have a look at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we are talking about orientation, they are 2 things that come into the picture:

1. Device Orientation
2. Interface Orientation

As its clear by the name only, Device orientation tells, in which orientation device is, and Interface orientation says in which orientation your app is presenting its interface.

**"I want the VC to be locked to portrait but let the user the option to
see the full image in both orientation."**

By this, its clear that you don't want to change interface of your App. What you want is to rotate the image, when device orientation is changes.

For that, First thing you should do is, have a look at this method  `beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications`

Write this to get notified each time when Device orientation is changed
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

Now, in the viewController where you are showing the images, write this

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(deviceOrientationDidChange) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

In `deviceOrientationDidChange` method, rotate the image as per device orientation
Let me know if more info needed..

Answer (score 0):

when you present the image :

```
if (UIDeviceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation))
{
UIImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI + M_PI_2);     
}
```

This should work, but I did not test it!

Comment: "I want the vc to be locked to portrait but let the user the option to see the full image in both orientation." This statement nullifes application of your answer. :(